# adjusting programm to count & save number of likes

Tags: javascript

I use a program for an online experiment that kind of simulate a facebook page with self descriptions of the one real participant in each session and other artificial profiles. There is a like button (.btn-like) under each description to click on.

The number of likes by the artificial others is already set and if the participant receives likes, it gets displayed to him/her by a text.

It would be interesting for me to count the number of likes the participant is giving to others. I don't know where to access this information in this script. Can anyone help me please?    Thanks in advance

// Initialize like buttons

```
  $('.btn-like').on('click', function() {
      $(this).prev().text(parseInt($(this).prev().text()) + 1);
  // Like buttons can only be clicked once
      $(this).attr("disabled", true);
  });



**// When user receives likes**
  $('.userslikes').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var usernames = $(this).data('usernames').split(",");
    var times = $(this).data('likes').split(",");

    for(var i=0; i<times.length; i++) 
    { 
        times[i] = +times[i]; 

        themsg = usernames[i] + " likes your description";

        setTimeout(function(themsg) {
            that.text(parseInt(that.text()) + 1);
            alertify.success(themsg)

        }, times[i], themsg);
    }       
  });

// When others receive likes
  $('.otherslikes').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var times = $(this).data('likes').split(",");

    for(var i=0; i<times.length; i++) 
    { 
        times[i] = +times[i]; 

        setTimeout(function () {
            that.text(parseInt(that.text()) + 1);
        }, times[i]);
    } 
  });
```